# How can I check user authentication and redirect to proper pages in my SvelteKit SPA?

Tags: authentication, jwt, single-page-application, svelte, sveltekit

I'm creating a SPA website with SvelteKit and I want to check user authentication (from an external API).

Some pages are only allowed for unlogged users (`/login`, `/register`), and some others are only allowed for logged users (`/dashboard/**`).
So if an unlogged user enters the `/dashboard` page, my site should redirect him to `/login`. If a logged in user wants to join the `/loggin` page, he should be redirected to `/dashboard`.

I also add that I use `data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover"` on the `<body>` to improve the performance of my website.

I am currently trying to check the authentication from `+layout.ts` and `+page.ts`.

To do this, I am doing this:

```js
// /src/routes/(unauthed)/+layout.ts
// We are in the UNAUTHED routes group, which includes /login and /register.
export const load: LayoutLoad = async () => {
  if (cookies.get('JWT')) {
    ;(await apiAuth.verify()).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        // If the user is authenticated, we want to redirect him to the Dashboard
        throw redirect(300, '/dashboard')
      },
    })
  }
  return {}
}
```

```js
// /src/routes/(authed)/+layout.ts
// We are in the AUTHED routes group, which includes /dashboard/**.
export const load: LayoutLoad = async () => {
  if (cookies.get('JWT')) {
    ;(await apiAuth.verify()).subscribe({
      error: () => {
        // If the user is not authenticated, we want to redirect him to the Login page
        throw redirect(300, '/login')
      },
    })
  } else {
    throw redirect(300, '/login')
  }
  return {}
}
```

(I created a `cookies` service to get the JWT cookie and an `apiAuth` service to make the HTTP request with fetch. So, in the `next()` callback, I get a successful response.)

However, it seems that `throw redirect()` does not work in the client side `load` function.
I also tried the same with `goto()` instead of `throw redirect()`, but, I don't know why, it creates a redirect loop...

Finally, I tried this:

```js
// /src/routes/(unauthed)/+layout.ts
// We are in the UNAUTHED routes group, which includes /login and /register.
export const load: LayoutLoad = async () => {
  if (cookies.get('JWT')) {
    ;(await apiAuth.verify()).subscribe({
      next: () => {
        // If the user is authenticated, we want to redirect him to the Dashboard
        redirect.set('/dashboard')
      },
    })
  }
  return {}
}
```

```js
// /src/routes/(authed)/+layout.ts
// We are in the AUTHED routes group, which includes /dashboard/**.
export const load: LayoutLoad = async () => {
  if (cookies.get('JWT')) {
    ;(await apiAuth.verify()).subscribe({
      error: () => {
        // If the user is not authenticated, we want to redirect him to the Login page
        redirect.set('/login')
      },
    })
  } else {
    redirect.set('/login')
  }
  return {}
}
```

```js
// /src/routes/+layout.svelte
// We are in the MAIN layout.
redirect.subscribe(value => {
  // When redirect is updated, redirect to the wanted page
  goto(value)
})
```

(`redirect` is a store.)

But this solution doesn't work because I get redirected when I hover over a link (because of the `data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover"`).

So, how to create a good auth checked in my SPA SveltKit app?